# The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Exercise 1.3

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be a variety given by a single equation. Prove that a point $P\in V$ is nonsingular if and only if $$\text{dim}_{\bar{K}}M_P/M_P^2=\text{dim}V.$$

For a general variety $V$, this equality holds. I am trying to prove this particular case.

Thank you!

---

$\text{dim}V$: the transcendence degree of $\bar{K}(V)$ over $\bar{K}$

$M_P=\{f\in \bar{K}[V]:f(P)=0\}$ (a maximal ideal of $\bar{K}[V]$)

$P\in V$ is nonsingular if the matrix $$\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_1}(P)\dots\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_n}(P)\bigg)$$ has rank $1$.

Comment: What's your definition of a nonsingular point and of dimension?

Comment: I added the definitions.

Comment: This is often called Jacobian criterion. It states that a non-singular point have a regular local ring (your property above). For a proof see for instance http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/caag1/jayanthan.pdf in page 3